# How do i modify each value of a deep nested list recursively and return another similar list?

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested

I want to take a nested list

```
[[[1,2],[4,5]], 1, [1,3,4],[2,3,4]]
```

go in there recursively, modify each value, and then return a similar list. For example say i wanted to add 1 to each value the output would be

```
[[[2,3],[5,6]], 2, [2,4,5],[3,4,5]]
```

I've made some progress doing this with making a recursive function where i test if it's a list or a element to modify. I'm stumped when it comes to how to compile the list again. Isn't there a simple way to do this? The following code is what i have so far.

```
def add1(nodelist):
    list_of_lists = []
    name_nodes.nodes = []
    def recurse_list(nodelist):
        name_nodes.nodes = []
        edit_list = False
        for r in nodelist:
            if type(r) == list:
                recurse_list(r)
            else:
                edit_list = True
                name_nodes.nodes.append(r+1)
        if edit_list == True:
            list_of_lists.append(name_nodes.nodes)
    recurse_list(nodelist)
    return list_of_lists
```

This code gets me the following output

```
[[2, 3], [5, 6, 2], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```

I'm surprised there's not some module or some built in functionality to better handle nested lists because there are so many questions handling similar but different behavior. The closest question i could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python). But that just didn't have exactly what i was looking for. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: "if it's a list or a [sic] element to modify" -- this cannot always be done in a 100%-sure manner in Python.

Answer (score 3):

```
def add1(L):
    for i, elem in enumerate(L):
        if isinstance(elem, int):
            L[i] += 1
        else:
            L[i] = add1(elem)
    return L
```

Output:

```
>>> L = [[[1,2],[4,5]], 1, [1,3,4],[2,3,4]]
>>> add1(L)
[[[2, 3], [5, 6]], 2, [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: It's so beautiful i'm going to cry. I made a few modifications. I changed `L[i] += 1` to `L[i] = func(elem)` and changed `isinstance(elem, int)` to `not isinstance(elem, list)` added func in the arguement list and renamed it to nmap. Now i can changed a nested list easily. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've been thinking about this lately.  Here's a part of the code I've written for this, an excerpt taken from some demonstration.  The function `nmap()` works like the `map()` built-in function, but it works with nested lists.

```
import functools


def mapper_nester(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*point):
        try:
            res = function(*point)
        except TypeError:
            res = map(mapper_nester(function), *point)
        return res
    return wrapper


def nmap(function, *seq):
    """nmap(funtion, seq[, seq ...]) -> nested list of similar structure."""
    return map(mapper_nester(function), *seq)

>>> nested_list = [0, [1], [[[[2]]]],
                   [3, [], [4, 5]],
                   [6, [7, 8],
                    9, [[[]], 10, []]], 11,
                   [], [], [12]]
>>> nmap(lambda x: x + 1, nested_list)
[1,
 [2],
 [[[[3]]]],
 [4, [], [5, 6]],
 [7, [8, 9], 10, [[[]], 11, []]],
 12,
 [],
 [],
 [13]]
```

This is a recursive function that traverses the nested (recursive) structure.

Pros:

- Should work for your case.
- Does not use `isinstance()` [which tends to be confusing and not do what you really want to do](https://web.archive.org/web/20130723051433/http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/).
- It's just a few lines.

Cons:

- It is subjected to the recursion limit, so not really useful for deeply nested lists.
- In Python context, recursive functions are frowned upon in general.
- This function uses `TypeError` to check for the node's "type" (atom or collection-of-atoms), but this is not always reliable (and is dependent on what the mapped function actually do), especially with Python duck typing.

Actually I've written a lot more code just to address the last issue, but it's quite cumbersome to put into here.[1]

[1] What it does is to create a temporary, limited "typed universe" which clearly distinguishes atoms from collections-of-atoms (this is done in an ugly manner, using `isinstance()` and friends, and the creation of this "typed universe" can be customized), and then to lift both the data and the to-be-mapped function into this universe, where the lifted function can only act on atoms and produce atoms as value.  The nested-map is done in this universe, and the result is then optionally demoted to the usual Python universe.